# Injecting ejb instances into the servlet, @EJB injects null - JBoss6

Tags: cdi, ejb-3.1, servlet-3.0

I am developing an enterprise app using ejb 3.1 and servlets 3.0 that runs in jboss 6.1.0. I deploy the jar and war as separate copies in the same jboss instance. I inject the ejb (remote interface instance) into the servlet using the @EJB(mappedname="beanname/remote"), but I always get it null! I have tried to deploy the jar and war bind into a single copy, ie, had the ejb-jar into the web-inf/lib/ folder of the war file. Also, I have the beans.xml inside both the meta-inf of the ejb-jar and web-inf of the war files. why is the ejb not injected into the servlet? did I missed anything?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can put EJBs (local EJBs) into WARs now. If you need to use a remote EJB then you need to go with an EAR deployment.

Also AS6 is no longer under active development, you may want to try a more current version.